# General solution for $\cos(5x) = \sin(5x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find the general solution of the following equation for $x∈\mathbb R$:

$\cos(5x) = \sin(5x)$

Believe me, I have no clues how to begin....

Comment: can you solve $\cos(y)=\sin(y)$?

Comment: Nope @Tanner, just beginning to learn and was thrown down this question as first assignment.

Comment: can you solve $\tan(y)=1$?

Comment: Draw a picture of a circle and *guess* where $\sin x = \cos x$.   There are values where they obviously *aren't* equal and if you look at the picture you can see an *obvious* requirement for $\sin x = \cos x$ so that the answer will be clear.  but be careful about $\sin 5x=\cos 5x$ theres another thing to beware of.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\cos(5x)=\sin(5x)\iff \tan(5x)=1\iff 5x=\dfrac\pi 4+n\pi, n\in\mathbb Z$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: May have given too much information as there is not much more that needs to be done from here.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by letting $y=5x$.

Then $$\cos y = \sin y$$

First note that no solution to $\cos y =0$ solves this equation, so division throughout by $\cos y$ is allowed.

You get $\tan y = 1$.

At this point, you should be able to continue. Remember the periodicity of the tangent function (careful, the period is *not* $2\pi$) and don't forget to reverse the original substitution.